# How to determine a file is tab delimited in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a script that I am working on that reads in some text files and converts them to .csv and changes some values.  I have two different file sources.  One is a tab delimited .txt file and the other is a comma separated .txt file.  Is there a way to determine which type of delimiter is being used to determine which export function is appropriate?

```
get-childitem $workingDir -filter *.txt -Recurse| ForEach-Object {
   
$targetfile = $_.Name
$targetFile = $_.FullName.Substring(0,$_.FullName.Length-4)
$targetFile = $targetfile += ".csv"

if( Get-Content -Delimiter = `t ){
    Write-Host "The file is tab-delimited"
    Get-Content -path $_.FullName 
    ForEach-Object {$_ -replace “`t”,”,” } |  
    Out-File -filepath $targetFile -Encoding utf8 
}

else {
    Write-Host "The file is comma-separated"
    Get-Content -path $_.FullName | 
    Out-File -filepath $targetFile -Encoding utf8 
}
}
```

Comment: Read the first line and test it it has more tabs than commas :)

Comment: Possible to read the first line and check if it is a valid object with both methods? Is it fair to say that the comma delimited file would not contain ANY tabs or vice versa?

Comment: @mhouston100, you can _infer_ from what answer was accepted answer that comma-separated files are indeed assumed not to contain tabs. The other answer shows how to check the first line only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to use `Select-String` to check for tab character and set delimiter.

```
if(Get-Content $csvfile -First 1 | Select-String -Pattern "`t")
{
    $delim = "`t"
}
else
{
    $delim = ','
}

Import-Csv $csvfile -Delimiter $delim
```

Comment: It's certainly a concise solution, and you could improve it with `-Quiet`, which (a) stops after the first match and (b) only outputs a _Boolean_. However, it is still somewhat inefficient if the file is comma-separated, because the absence of a tab then requires `Select-String` to still read the _whole_ file; it's more efficient to look at the _first_ input line only.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the comma-separated files never contain tabs (which would then be *data*), **the most efficient approach is to inspect only the *first* line of each file for the presence of tab characters**, which is most easily done with `` (Get-Content -First 1 $_.FullName) -match "`t" ``  - see [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and `-match`, the [regular-expression matching operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match).

```
# Determine the arguments to pass to Set-Content - later, via splatting - 
# for writing the output file.
$setContentArgs = @{
  LiteralPath = $_.BaseName + '.csv'
  Encoding = 'utf8'
}

# Check the 1st line for containing a tab.
# (This assumes that the comma-separated files contain not tabs as data.)
if ((Get-Content -First 1 $_.FullName) -match "`t") {
  Write-Host "The file is tab-delimited."
  # Read line by line, replace tabs with commas, and write with UTF-8 encoding.
  Get-Content $_.FullName | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "`t", ',' } |
    Set-Content @setContentArgs
} 
else {
  Write-Host "The file is comma-separated."
  # Just read lines as-is and write with UTF-8 encoding.
  Get-Content $_.FullName |
    Set-Content @setContentArgs
}
```

- Note the use of the `.BaseName` property on the input [`[System.IO.FileInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo), which conveniently  reports the file name *without its extension*, which allows you to simply append the new extension.
- Since you're dealing with *text* (strings) only, [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content), which is slightly more efficient, is preferable to [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file).
- For the technique of passing arguments via a *hashtable* (`@{ ... }`), see  [`about_Splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)

---

If the files are smallish (easily fit into memory as a whole (possibly twice) each), you can **significantly speed up processing by reading each file *as a whole* with `-Raw`** and using
`-NoNewLine` (PSv5+) to write that (possibly modified) string as-is, without appending a trailing newline, to the output file.

Since you're then reading the entire file anyway, you can get away with a single `Get-Content` call and apply `` -replace "`t", ',' `` blindly, given that for comma-separated files this will simply be a (fast) no op.

```
(Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName) -replace "`t", ',' |
  Set-Content ($_.BaseName + '.csv') -Encoding Utf8 -NoNewLine
```

Comment: I always learn something from your detailed posts. Thanks for sharing your knowledge! This is the best answer IMO.

Answer (score -1):

I will use `Import-Csv` for this:

```
If(Import-Csv "File path to test if Tab-delimited file" -Delimiter "`t" -Ea SilentlyContinue){
  "File is tab-delimited"
}
If(Import-Csv "File path to test if Comma-CSV file" -Ea SilentlyContinue){
  "File is a comma-separated CSV"
}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement import-csv and I receive this error 'A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ' '.'
The file i am trying on this test is the comma separated text file.

Comment: Oh sorry made the edit you need `-Ea SilentlyContinue`

Comment: (Assuming the input file exists) you won't get an error either way, because in the absence of the specified or implied delimiter PowerShell simply reads the file as containing a _single_ column, spanning the _whole_ line. In other words: your test won't work.